# Music and Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, sound

I posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4029880/music-and-fourier-transform) on MathStackExchange. My question is in here now: How can I program a Fourier Tranform of a plot without knowing the function that generates the plot, assuming the funcion is of the form
$$\sum_{n}\sin(2\pi n)?$$
As I said in my earlier post: This is an unrigorous project. Don't worry about real-world application or what would be the fastest way. I'm just very curious how one could program such a Transform in Mathematica.

Comment: So, how would you get the function? As a list of values? In other words, in what physical form should we expect the input of your Fourier transform?

Comment: What if I play an A4 note on my piano, without backgroundnoises, and record it?

Comment: Use the command Fourier. It takes a list (like your sampled piano) and calculates the spectrum.

Comment: How does this command work? What are is the idea behind it? Can I program "my own" easy Fourier comman?

Comment: It's called the FFT (Fast Fourier Transform). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform

Comment: Could you help me program a FFT of a wave, without using the command Fourier?

Comment: @vitamind To be frank, that would only be interesting as an exercise for you, but nobody in their right mind will go re-implementing the FFT algorithm, when perfectly good standard implementations exist. In fact, I suspect that even the one in Mathematica probably relies on an underlying fast optimized library of some kind. To see how `Fourier` works, search Fourier transform on this website and you will find a ton of answers. FFT is a topic that comes up often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the slow Fourier transform... call it the SFT... it's basically the same as the FFT, but slower. On the positive side, it's not hard to program. Let x be the list that you want to take the transform of. The formula implemented is:

[image]

where N is the length of x. In Mathematica, this is:

```
 X[k_] :=  Sum[x[[n + 1]] Exp[-I 2 Pi k n/Length[x]], {n, 0, Length[x] - 1}]
```

You can evaluate this for all n terms using

```
X[#] & /@ Range[Length[x]]
```

OK. It's not really called the Slow Fourier Transform. It's called the "Discrete Fourier Transform," or [DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform). MarcoB already thinks I'm not in my right mind, so I better stop here.

Comment: Time for you to do something. Take a lot of samples of your function, call them x, then the transform will be X as defined above.

Comment: I understand the mathematical computation now. Thank you very much. I will come back to inform you if I was able to program it.

Comment: Okay I did it. Only one small question: What's the command to find a function-value of a plot? So I only I have plot, I put in $2$ and then I get the value of that plot at $2$.

Comment: @bills Hehe. I like the Slow Fourier Transform though :-)